# Need help refactoring a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am querying the zippopotam.us Zip Code lookup service to return City info.
This stand alone code block works:

```
$("#studentPostCode").blur(function() {
  var zip_in = $(this);
  if (zip_in.val().length == 5) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.zippopotam.us/SE/" + zip_in.val(),
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(result, success) {
        // Accept the first result
        var places0 = result['places'][0];
        var placeName = places0['place name'];
        $("#studentCity").val(placeName);
      },
      error: function(result, success) {}
    });
  }
});
```

However when I try to refactor so I can use it in other places, it breaks.
My efforts:

```
//calls
$("#studentPostCode").blur(function() {
  var pCode0 = $(this);
  var myCity0 = getPlaceFromPostCode(pCode0);
  $("#studentCity").val(myCity0);
});

$("#guardian1PostCode").blur(function() {
  var pCode1 = $(this);
  var myCity1 = getPlaceFromPostCode(pCode1);
  $("#guardian1City").val(myCity1);
});

//function refactored as:
$(function getPlaceFromPostCode(pCodeX) {
  var zip_in = pCodeX;
  if (zip_in.val().length == 5) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.zippopotam.us/SE/" + zip_in.val(),
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(result, success) {
        // Accept the first result
        var places0 = result['places'][0];
        var placeName = places0['place name'];
        return placeName;
      },
      error: function(result, success) {}
    });
  }
});
```

This returns "placeName" as undefined.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show what Ajax returns?

Comment: Actually your `placeName` should return correct value as long as `zip_in.val()` is in [valid range](http://zippopotam.us/) of `10005 - 98499`. But your function will also not return `placeName` since you re running an asynchronous request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return placeName;` statement in the success handler is ignored, as the function itself is called asynchronously and the `getPlaceFromPostCode` method does not return anything. Try something along the lines of:

```
function getPlaceFromPostCode(pCodeX, cityCallback) {
  //... the $.ajax call
  success: function(result, success) {
    // Accept the first result
    var places0 = result['places'][0];
    var placeName = places0['place name'];
    cityCallback(placeName);
  }, //... etc
}
```

and then to call the function (there's probably an easier shorthand for this as well instead of a full-blown function):

```
getPlaceFromPostCode(pCode1, function(city){
  $("#guardian1City").val(city);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work, then you should add async: false in your $.ajax, because $.ajax is async, you are getting undefined. If you want it to be aysnc then you should go something with promise.

Comment: That's really bad advice, and wouldn't even work because the function is still not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because the request takes some time to finish, it might make more sense to pass in the item that changes as a variable to the function, and then have the function use the data from the item to get the zip code and then later update the `input` box when the call is successful.

```js
function updateInputByZipCode(inputElementToRead) {
  var zipCode = $(inputElementToRead).val();
  if (zipCode.length == 5) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.zippopotam.us/US/" + zipCode,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(result, success) {
        // Accept the first result
        var places0 = result['places'][0];
        var placeName = places0['place name'];
        $('#' + $(inputElementToRead).attr('output')).val(placeName);
      },
      error: function(result, success) {}
    });
  }
}

//calls
$("#studentPostCode, #guardianPostCode").blur(function() {
  updateInputByZipCode(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="studentPostCode" output="studentCity" value="32003"/>
<input id="guardianPostCode" output="guardianCity" value="10005"/><br>
<input id="studentCity"/>
<input id="guardianCity"/>
```